# UTF-8 escape sequence error while connecting NodeJS to MarkLogic as SAML

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to connect NodeJS program to MarkLogic using SAML. Following is the code snippet.

```
var mytoken = fs.readFileSync('./token.token', 'ascii');
//mytoken = utf8.encode(mytoken);
console.log(mytoken);
var options = {
    port: '8060',
    authType: 'saml',
    ssl: true,
    token: mytoken,
    key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/localhost.key', 'ascii'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/localhost.crt', 'ascii')
  };

  var db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(options);
  db.documents.query(
    qb.where(
      qb.term('water')
    )).result(function(response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    });
```

and following is the error that I am getting.

```
body: {
    errorResponse: {
      statusCode: 500,
      status: 'Internal Server Error',
      messageCode: 'INTERNAL ERROR',
      message: 'XDMP-UTF8SEQ: Invalid UTF-8 escape sequence . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.'
    }
  }
}
```

1. My token is correct. I have tested it in jwt.ms
2. SSL certificates are working fine. I tested using auth type "Digest" and I was able to connect
3. I tried adding bearer: in front of token but of no help.
4. I printed token on the console and it is getting printed well.

Thanks for your help on this. I would appreciate any clue.

Comment: You are reading the files as ascii `cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/localhost.crt', 'ascii')` Have you tried reading the contents with UTF-8 encoding: `encoding:'utf8'`?

Comment: I tried following two ways and none of them worked.
var mytoken = fs.readFileSync('./token.token', 'utf8');

I also tried installing npm library utf8 and tried following code.
mytoken = utf8.encode(mytoken);

Comment: The SAML token must be base 64 encoded. If the token.token file is produced from the JWT payload, it must encode the SAML token in the same way as the value of the SAMLResponse form field from an IDP.

Comment: Thanks Ehennum. I guess, I got your point.  Let me try couple of things and get back to you with more details. Thanks much.

Comment: @ehennum THANKS A TON ! You are a life saver. It worked for me. I was working on two separate apps. 1. REACT JS 2. Node JS . I was doing authentication using React app against Azure AD, getting the token, copying pasting token, manually in Node JS. And I was doing a stupid mistake. My REACT app was not fetching me SAML token rather it was authentication token. After I read your comment, I got the clue. I made changes, used the tool name "SAML-tracer", got the SAML token and it worked like charms for me. THANKS MUCH.

Comment: Great, glad to hear that you puzzled out the root issue and found the path to success.